# How to add multiple values in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

        public class Test1 {
            private String Type;
            private String value;
            @XmlElement(name="type")
            public final String getType(){
                return Type;
            }
            public final void setType(final String type){
                this.Type=type;
            }
            @XmlElement(name="value")
            public final String getValue(){
                return value;
            }
            public final void setValue(final String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name="test") 
    public class Test2 {
        ArrayList<Test1> test1;
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="users") 
        @XmlElement(name="user")
        public final ArrayList<Test1> getUser(){

            return test1;
        }
        public final void setUser(final ArrayList<Test1> mm){
            this.test1=mm;
        }
    }
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import com.covidien.laptopagent.xml.XMLUserLogin;



public class TEST {

    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        Test1 test1=new Test1();
        test1.setType("100");
        test1.setValue("none");
        test1.setType("101");
        test1.setValue("ok");
        ArrayList<Test1> permfile=new ArrayList<Test1>();
        permfile.add(test1);


        ArrayList<Test2>test2 =new ArrayList<Test2>();
        Test2 test2obj=new Test2();
        test2obj.setuser(permfile);




        JAXBContext context;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLUserLogin.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(test2, System.out);
            System.out.println();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Excepted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
   ......
  <users>
         <user>
               <type>100</type>
               <value>none</value>
         </user>
         <user>
                 <type>101</type>
                 <value>ok</value>
          </user>
</users>
...............
...............
</test>
```

but it returns only one value of user:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
   ......
  <users>
         <user>
               <type>100</type>
               <value>none</value>
         </user>
</users>
...............
...............
</test>
```

How to solve this? can someone help me what am i did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the code like this

```
    Test1 user1=new Test1();
    user1.setType("100");
    user1.setValue("none");

    Test1 user2=new Test1();
    user2.setType("101");
    user2.setValue("ok");

    ArrayList<Test1> permfile=new ArrayList<Test1>();
    permfile.add(user1);
    permfile.add(user2);
```